# Converting from binary to original array values

Tags: arrays, matlab

Given a 2D array that has been converted to binary, for some index values of the binary array how do you find the corresponding values in the original?

Maybe something using ind2sub?

Answer (score 5):

No, you can index directly.

```
%# create some test data
m = magic(4);
%# make binary image
bw = m>10;

%# read values from m
values = m(bw);

%# alternatively, if you have linear indices (as found via find)...
linIdx = find(bw);
%# ...you can use that instead
values = m(linIdx);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the 2D structure using an element-wise multiplication.

```
m = magic(4);
bw = m>10;
m .* bw
```